# HorizontalScrollView hides its child views

Tags: android, xml, horizontalscrollview, android-relativelayout

Whenever i enclose my custom viewws with horizontal scrollview tags in xml file, the views seem to disappear.
In previous related questions it is mentioned as

> "Horizontal scroll view hides its children if you set
>   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" for inner container."

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

    <com.example.mahikanthnag.cs.views.StateProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:spb_currentStateNumber="three"
        app:spb_maxStateNumber="four"
        app:spb_stateBackgroundColor="#BDBDBD"
        app:spb_stateForegroundColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateNumberBackgroundColor="#808080"
        app:spb_stateNumberForegroundColor="#eeeeee"
        app:spb_currentStateDescriptionColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateDescriptionColor="#808080"
        app:spb_animateToCurrentProgressState="true"
        app:spb_checkStateCompleted="true"
        />

    <com.example.mahikanthnag.cs.views.StateProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:spb_currentStateNumber="three"
        app:spb_maxStateNumber="four"
        app:spb_stateBackgroundColor="#BDBDBD"
        app:spb_stateForegroundColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateNumberBackgroundColor="#808080"
        app:spb_stateNumberForegroundColor="#eeeeee"
        app:spb_currentStateDescriptionColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateDescriptionColor="#808080"
        app:spb_animateToCurrentProgressState="true"
        app:spb_checkStateCompleted="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id"
        />

    <com.example.mahikanthnag.cs.views.StateProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:spb_currentStateNumber="three"
        app:spb_maxStateNumber="four"
        app:spb_stateBackgroundColor="#BDBDBD"
        app:spb_stateForegroundColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateNumberBackgroundColor="#808080"
        app:spb_stateNumberForegroundColor="#eeeeee"
        app:spb_currentStateDescriptionColor="#009688"
        app:spb_stateDescriptionColor="#808080"
        app:spb_animateToCurrentProgressState="true"
        app:spb_checkStateCompleted="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/your_state_progress_bar_id1"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

But in my case I dont have android:layout_gravity attribute at all. How do i solve this?

This is my layout xml file where i added cutom views

Any suggestion is welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linear Layout instead of Relative Layout like below:

```
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <HorizontalScrollView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:scrollbars="none">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/travelGallery"
                                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                                     <Your view 1/>
                                     <Your view 2/>
                                     <Your view n/>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </HorizontalScrollView>
                        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used LinearLayout too, but the result is same. Is there any other way

Comment: The above code works fine with me. Or you can do another thing. Keep your views inside a separate layout file and inflate it into the parent Layout. In my case the parent Layout is `travelGallery`. If you need I can give you a sample code.

Comment: thanks sam, the first solution actually worked for me. Did some mistake the other day. Thank you :)